# Cant figure out what movie this is, Its not “Night of the Demons”

Tags: story-identification, horror

Seen this movie a long while back when i was a kid & i want to re-watch it but i cant figure out the actual name. I've looked it up before but its not "Night of the Demons". Its similar but different. If i remember correctly, its starts off on Halloween & its Night time. There's a house party of sorts, some guy on a balcony is shooting kids on the street with a paintball gun. Something happens with the party, it ends but idk how. Theres a group of people looking in a basement, someone finds objects or figures & it activates some demons. So no one cant leave the house until daylight. The ending-ish scene shows mirrors, & some demons. Eventually its day time & a few people leave. Its a really low production kinda movie, low quality. Either 2000s or before

Again, its not Night of the Demons. That movie has a group of people doing some chant seance. Thanks in advance, hopefully someone can help

Comment: This sounds a bit like the Buffy episode "Fear, Itself", except for the paintball part. http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Fear,_Itself

Comment: There are a few 'Night of the Demons', one in 2009, one in 1988, and some sequels. You sure it's none of them?